# Pie Chart in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, input, visualization, libraries

so my objective is to test a piechart from a code i found for visualizing stocks, kind of a portfolio. The problem is, that i always get an error. I tried using the jupyter notebook, which isnt as useful as I thougt. I am working with User Inputs. In the following are the libraries I used and the full code. Thanks in advance.

import datetime
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go

https://github.com/NoamYakarOfficial/StockPortfolioVisualizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

- **it's working Vs code**
- **can you check the python version or python extension install vs code,
  after opening the terminal install packages**

---

**Can you run this way:**

```
pip install yfinance

pip install plotly
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I get as well, but I cant get to see the visualizer, thats the problem.